# How to set Button position after all Recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-button

Hello:)I have some activity with RecyclerView and Button. I want the button to be positioned after all the items of the Recyclerview. I'm trying to do this, but the button either crawls out of the screen or locks in one place.  How I can do it?
My XML with RecyclerView and Button:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".TestText"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lineartest"
    >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewtest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/test"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verify_button"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"

        android:text="Проверить"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerviewtest"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to show button after each item of recyclerview than you have to add Button on adapter.

Comment: @NadimAnsari, No I want set button after recyclerview

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: @NadimAnsari, I don't know, I've tried different layouts, but the button either goes out of the screen and is not available, or is fixed to the bottom of the screen when scrolling